# What is the difference between a direct method and a device method?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Hopefully this isn't a silly question...

What is the difference between a direct method and a device method in the Azure IoT Hub?

From what I understand, a direct method can be invoked from the IoT Hub in Azure to send a "direct method" to be executed on the connected device.

However, I have also read that this is what a device method does.

Are device methods and direct methods the same thing? I have read the Microsoft documentation (I'm using the C sdk on an embedded system) and my understanding is no clearer.

Can anyone clear this up for me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you include links to the documentation where it mentions each? My assumption is that they probably mean the same thing. Usually the wording in "Direct Method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods  then both means same thing

Comment: This documentation is what I meant, thanks for your help